# Hierarchy of variables using my own metric (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, hierarchy, metrics

I have 7 variables: A, B, C, D, E, F, and G. I have devised my own metric for an assignment that compares 2 variables and returns a scalar number. The closer the metric between 2 variables, the closer those variables are related. For example, if I compared A and B and got 2.2, then compare A and C and got 3.3, then A and B are more similar than A and C.

I want to prepare a hierarchy map, maybe something like a cluster or tree diagram that will map out the similarities if I assign all the combinations of similarities.

I know in MATLAB this is done via the linkage function, but the linkage function in MATLAB gives me precanned metrics for comparison such as "euclidean". I don't need this, I want to just put in my own metrics and map out the distances.

Does anyone have any insight on how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab **pdist** function allows you to compute a custom pairwise distance metric if you supply a function handle to a function you code that computes the distance.

The syntax is just

> my_distance= pdist(pairs, @your_function)

where pairs is the data matrix containing your pairs, and @your_function is a handle to a custom distance metric function you define.

For specific requirements on the custom distance function syntax see the Matlab documentation for **pdist**.

You can then use the distance computed in the hierarchical clustering routines of the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox, which I assumed you have because you mentioned **linkage**

Comment: In your problem you'd want a matrix of values representing whatever your measurements are so that you have all measurements between all pairings of your 7 input variables.

Comment: Ah, okay, so it'd be a 7 by 7 matrix, with perhaps A B C D E F G on the X-axis and A B C D E F G on the y-axis. So the intersection of B and D on the matrix would represent the metric when B and D are compared, correct?

Comment: That's basically it. Check the documentation if you have more than one observation for each variable, I think it will handle that case if you construct it properly.

Comment: Awesome, last request: anyway to change the titles of the x-axis to from A B C to stuff like "cats", "dogs", "birds", etc?